# Getting error on running docker-compose up

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run my python code through docker-compose. It is not a flask app so I didn't provide a port number on my yml file. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:   
  main:
    build: .
    image: ddn4
    environment:
      - neo4j_uri=bolt://54.209.5.141:7687
      - neo4j_username=neo4j
      - password=provis234
      - blob_conn_string=httpsxxxx
```

main.py is my python code. After running

> docker-compose build

, I get that an image was successfully built. Also, upon checking using

> docker images

, I see that the image ddn4 was built successfully. But upon running

> docker-compose up

, I am getting the following error:

> main_1  | Error !!!! File Exception:
> main_1  | 'function' object is not subscriptable
> main_1  | Error !!!!:
> main_1  | 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns' dd-n4_main_1 exited with code 0

dd-n4 is the location of my dockerfile, requirements.txt, python codes and docker-compose.yml file.

Here is the python code for the variables which seem to be causing the error:

```
def neo4jconn():
    """
    This code is to create a connection string for connecting to Neo4j
    """
    try:
       
        neo_conn = Graph(os.getenv['neo4j_uri'], user=os.getenv['neo4j_username'], password=os.getenv['password'])
        return neo_conn
        

    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error !!!!:')
        print(ex)
```

Comment: you should use only `docker-compose up` for running docker-compose.yml file, if you would like to re-build it add `--build` flas, it looks like: `docker-compose up --build`.does it work successfully locally?what is your docker file?

Comment: My dockerfile works successfully locally. I think the issue is with my environment variables that I have used on python. I am getting the same error on using docker-compose up --build

Comment: Can you run this code in your host Python environment?  (I would normally expect `os.getenv()` to be a function, and `os.environ[]` to be a dictionary, but you should see this same error running the same code in a virtual environment without involving Docker.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get it resolved by updating my python code to use os.getenv() instead of os.getenv[]. Thanks @David Maze

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use both build and image statement.
If you use build the built image will automatically be used !

Comment: I am getting this because of reference to the python environment variables not because of the docker-compose commands. Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: reference? did you mean that your env vars is not available in your container?

Comment: I have added the environment variables in my yaml file as you can see above. I am not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: The [Compose `image:` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image) describes what happens if you have both `build:` and `image:`; it is a reasonable combination in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

try to use docker-compose up for running docker-compose.yml file, if you would like to re-build it add --build flag, detach mode add -d, it looks like:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

you can pass all of the environment variables to .env file and install additionaly [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/):

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

and pass it to docker-compose:

```
  youre_service:
    image: image:1.7
    container_name: container
    env_file:
      - .env
```